# How to show disabled options in the combobox of Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, combobox, kendo-ui

Is it possible to enable the visiblility of disabled options in the Kendo UI combobox?

The result should be like this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_disabled

The problem is that the Kendo UI is removing all options with an disabled-attribute. You can try this at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index

Answer (score 0):

In `li` template add class to disabled items and apply CSS:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: gray;
}
```